# VSIX installer not compatible with VS2017 and VS2019

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, vs-extensibility, vsixmanifest

I'm using the following **extension.vsixmanifest** file to create my vsix package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema-design/2011">
  <Metadata>
    <Identity Id="774e58ba-f1b9-40a7-b676-834fa2c220fe" Version="1.0" Language="en-US" Publisher="Me" />
    <DisplayName>MyProduct</DisplayName>
    <Description xml:space="preserve">Description of my product</Description>
    <Icon>App.ico</Icon>
  </Metadata>
  <Installation AllUsers="true">
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[11.0, 17.0)" />
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[11.0, 17.0)" />
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" Version="[11.0, 17.0)"/>
  </Installation>
  <Dependencies>
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" Version="[4.5,)" />
  </Dependencies>
</PackageManifest>
```

When I try to install targeting **Visual Studio 2017** or **Visual Studio 2019**, I'm getting the following message:

[image]

Someone knows how could I address this issue?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017?view=vs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/breaking-changes-2017?view=vs-2019

Comment: Your company's support forum said in April 2017 that you had working VS2017 support.  What changed?  Did you get black-listed?

Comment: Yes, we're supporting VS2017 and VS2019. As our installer uses the "/q" option, the final user does not see the warning. I'm trying to understand why we're still seeing the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [need](https://learn.microsoft.com/ms-my/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017?view=vs-2017) `<Prerequisites>` section in the manifest:

> At a minimum, all extensions should specify the Visual Studio core
>   editor component as a prerequisite.